# Tweak with '%' (percent) symbol's catcode

Tags: package-writing, catcodes

I have the following code in my `main.tex`

```
  \catcode`\%=11
  \immediate\write18{git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h%x3b%ad" --date=short > \jobname.info}
  \catcode`\%=14
```

which extracts the version details from git. Now I want to put it in a `.sty` which I load at the beginning so I could re-use this macro. The code in the `.sty` file is:

```
\newcommand*{\getverhash}{\catcode`\%=11\immediate\write18{git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h%x3b%ad" --date=short > \jobname.info}\catcode`\%=14}
```

But the, even without calling the macro `\getverhash` I get the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
{\catcode `\%=11\immediate \write 18{git log -1 --pretty=format:"\par \ETC.
./main.tex:17: File ended while scanning use of \@argdef.
<inserted text>
\par
```

I guess the problem is with changing the catcode of the percent symbol (`%`) inside a package - but I don't know how to solve this. What is the right way to define `\getverhash` inside a package?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to being in a package, you would see the same if you used that in the preamble

```
\newcommand*{\getverhash}{\catcode`\%=11\immediate\write18{git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h%x3b%ad" --date=short > \jobname.info}\catcode`\%=14}
```

The argument to `\newcommand` (like any macro) is scanned before it is executed, so TeX is trying to find the closing `}` of the newcommand argument but does not find it because of the `%` The catcode changes would not apply until this command is *used* which is far too late.

```
\catcode`\%=11

    \newcommand*{\getverhash}{\immediate\write18{git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h%x3b%ad" --date=short > \jobname.info}

\catcode`\%=14
```

or simpler with no catcode changes

```
 \newcommand*{\getverhash}{\immediate\write18{git log -1 --pretty=format:"\@percentchar h\@percentchar x3b\@percentchar ad" --date=short > \jobname.info}
```